# Can't load image using picasso in onLoadFinished

Tags: android, image, picasso

```
import android.content.Intent;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
        import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
        import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

        import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
        import com.themovieapp.tonynguyen.themovieapp.data.MovieContract;

        public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

                if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.container, new DetailFragment())
                            .commit();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                int id = item.getItemId();

                //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

                private final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();

                private String mMovie;
                ImageView poster;



                private static final int DETAIL_LOADER = 0;

                private final String[] DETAIL_COLUMNS = {
                        MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MovieContract.MovieEntry._ID,
                        MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER
                };

                private static final int COL_MOVIE_POSTER = 1;

                public DetailFragment() {
                    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(DETAIL_LOADER, null, this);
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                }

                @Override
                public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "In onCreateLoader");
                    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                    if (intent == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return new CursorLoader(
                            getActivity(),
                            intent.getData(),
                            DETAIL_COLUMNS,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null
                    );
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {


                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "In onLoadFinished");
                    if (!data.moveToFirst()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    String posterURL = data.getString(COL_MOVIE_POSTER);


                    final String POSTERIMAGE_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
                    final String POSTERIMAGE_SIZE = "w500";

                    poster = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.poster_image_view);
                    final String POSTERIMAGE_URL = POSTERIMAGE_BASE_URL + POSTERIMAGE_SIZE + posterURL;


                    Picasso.with(this.getActivity()).load(POSTERIMAGE_URL).into(poster);
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Poster Urls: " + POSTERIMAGE_URL);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
                }

            }

        }
```

My app loads up images of movie poster in a Gridlayout. When I click the poster it will load up the DetailActivity and should display the poster i clicked on. How ever when i run my app and click the poster it crashes. I think the cause is the context in my picasso:

```
Picasso.with(this.getActivity()).load(POSTERIMAGE_URL).into(poster);
```

> 08-30 00:33:05.498 10812-10812/com.themovieapp.tonynguyen.themovieapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.themovieapp.tonynguyen.themovieapp, PID: 10812
>                                                                                           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
>                                                                                                at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
>                                                                                                at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.themovieapp.tonynguyen.themovieapp.DetailActivity$DetailFragment.onLoadFinished(DetailActivity.java:154)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.themovieapp.tonynguyen.themovieapp.DetailActivity$DetailFragment.onLoadFinished(DetailActivity.java:61)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:476)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:444)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:126)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:105)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:37)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:249)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:77)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:466)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$400(ModernAsyncTask.java:48)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:483)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: your loading path is null.

Comment: Your Imageview "poster" is null please check your Image View id in layout. Which is you pass in Picaso into part.

Comment: Thank you! I just checked and was using the wrong id. Sigh silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wrong with this line:

```
poster = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.poster_image_view);
```

Possibly your view does not have `R.id.poster_image_view` as an `ImageView` in the `R.layout.fragment_detail` layout

The error says that the target to accept an image is `null` (`into(poster)`)

Comment: Thank you! You were right I was using the wrong id.